# How to efficiently filter and sum by a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex where I would like to, as efficiently as possible:

1. Filter by one index (`flag & flag_filter != 0`)
2. Group and sum by the other two (`df.groupby(['time', 'sensor']).sum(['col1','col2','col3'])`)

So as a setup:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [
        range(0, 0xff),
        range(0, 5000),
        range(1, 3),
    ], names = ["flags", "time", "sensor"]
)

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": np.random.uniform(size=len(index), low=0.0, high=0.5),
    "col2": np.random.uniform(size=len(index), low=0.0, high=0.5),
    "col3": np.random.uniform(size=len(index), low=0.0, high=0.5),
}, index = index)
```

I'm hoping to get, from this, a DataFrame with the same columns, but an index of just `time, sensor`. The idea is we threw out rows that didn't match the filter, and summed the rows that did, while still maintaining the `time, sensor` grouping.

Comment: what is flag_filter?

Comment: @sammywemmy For the sake of this question, just an integer. I'm looking for rows that, when you bitwise AND their `flag` value against the `flag_filter` integer, have a non-zero result.

Comment: You should make your question more explicit and unambiguous. Kindly add the relevant details, make the sample example minimal, and add an expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Combine `.loc` with `droplevel`:

```py
# Let's say we want to filter for even flags
flag_filter = data.index.get_level_values("flags") % 2 == 0

# Select matching rows and drop the first level 
data.loc[flag_filter, :].droplevel(0)
```